# MaxMind Europe City too large on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, maxmind

I'm trying to use the MaxMind City Database, which is circa 36MB in size, in Google App Engine. Unfortunately GAE allows for a max file size of 32MB and the MaxMind API won't work when the file is stored on Google Storage.

Anyone figured a way. So far my only workaround is to load the "legacy" database, with the legacy API, which is only 27MB. Works fine, but I wonder what will happen if I ever have to rely on the main one...

Similar question, still unanswered: [Maxmind database file too large for AppEngine App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447536/maxmind-database-file-too-large-for-appengine-app)

thanks

Comment: Can't you put that file in your Cloud storage bucket and reference it from there?

Comment: Also you know App Engine already provides GEO headers? HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITY etc.

Comment: Hi stu. Thanks for your suggestion but storing on Storage doesn't work (tried) as the maxmind reader class does a lot of fseek, ftell a binary operations, somewhere in the code something breaks as it does read a wrong number of bytes and raises an exception. Also I need to lookup a vast amount of ip addresses stored in a log table , getting the location of the requestor of the page won't help.

Comment: There's a bug seeking past 524287 that's fixed in the 1.9.17 release. Suggest you try again when that comes out. If it still doesn't work then it's still a bug on our side we should fix. Also, we cache the result of the reads so it should be pretty quick once we've loaded up the file the first time.

Comment: Hi stu, thanks. Do you have the bug id and an expected release date?

Comment: Soon - send me your app_id and I can move you across to test it.

Comment: HI. This is my app id "appnexus-logfiles-groupm". Thanks

Comment: Ok can u give it a try?

Comment: Sure, i need some time to change the code. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi Stu, tested and still same issue. Note however that under AppEngine->Dashboard->Instances I still see 1.9.16 and not .17 (let me know if you want to switch to a different conversation method)

Comment: Ahh ok give sometimes that can happen - will need to wait a day or so

Comment: Hi @StuartLangley, just to let you know that after almost two days I still see 1.9.16

Comment: Yeh there's been a delay until next week.

Comment: Hi Stu, now I see 1.9.17 BUT *ALL* of my cron jobs that makes use of URLFetch fails, with a Google IO Exception!

Comment: Can you add a line to dump the URL that it's trying to access and perhaps the cURL error? Just uses syslog(LOG_DEBUG, ...) to write the log.

Comment: OK I know the problem. To work around it look for a line in Config.php like "'io_class'      => self::USE_AUTO_IO_SELECTION" and change it to "'io_class'      => 'Google_Io_Stream'"

Comment: Hi Stu, that fixed the issue, thanks. I will test the 1.9.17 with the MaxMind api mid of next week.

Comment: The 1.9.17 did NOT fix the issue,the Reader class of MaxMind still says that "The database contains corrupted data". ALSO, and this is much more problematic, since 1.9.17 I have erratic behaviour of the file_put_contents: some of my tasks reads a CSV file (with file_read_contents), add a header row or manipulate the data, and then rewrite it back (with file_put_contents).These writes now are failing with "Error 10" randomly (I can't see any pattern with filesize or other carachteristics of the files - the same file sometimes works, sometimes does not).Could you please go back to 1.9.16?

Comment: Hi Stu,I've seen you fixed it thanks to my comment on the G+ Google App Engine blog. Thank you, now all the files are being written perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use the lite version.  ;)  -- Looking at my GeoLiteCity.dat and it's only 18.7MB right now.  It might not be ideal for you but for my the lite version gets the job done... for free.

You can download it at http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Comment: Hi ca3le. I evaluated the light one but I need to lookup in Italy and the standard (paid) is quite bad here, let alone the free (tested, awful results)  just spent 200€, wanna make it worth 